# Serving static resources with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My goal is to configure the Spring MVC dispatcher servlet to serve static resources under /resources/ as described in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources.

With the configuration below and placing an index.html under any of `/resources`, `/resources/resources/` or `WEB-INF/resources` I still get a http 404 not found when sending a GET to `/resources/index.html`.

I am using the latest Spring 6.0.9. I also tried the annotation-based configuration as described under 4.2 and I can confirm that the code is executed during startup but the result is the same 404 not found.

Besides serving static resources the dynamic part of the Spring MVC application (Controllers etc.) works as expected.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <display-name>Backend Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:root-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:web-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**root-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="my.application"/>

<!-- database configuration -->

</beans>
```

**web-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.application"/>
    <mvc:cors>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
    </mvc:cors>
</beans>
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or just plain Spring?

Comment: Plain Spring MVC

Comment: Note that the mentioned website is mainly about Spring Boot. Did you try defining the `mvc:resources` tag in a `-servlet.xml` file instead of the `web.context.xml`?

Comment: On the mentioned website only section 2 is about Spring Boot. Section 3 and section 4 apply to Spring MVC. What is the full name of the `-servlet.xml` file? I don't think I have such a file.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC serves resources from `src/main/webapp/resources/` (and not `src/main/resources/`) per default. No additional configuration i. e. the `<mvc:resources>` tag mentioned above, is required.

I did not find the description of this behavior in the official Spring reference.